# UI bootstrap modal template url with function fails (Http request configuration url must be a string)

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, state

I recently upgraded angular 1.2.26 to 1.5.6 in one of our projects.

The idea was that the template url in state is like (my point is on the `templateUrl` all extra info is irrelevant):

```
.state("new.state", {
    url: "/some/url",
    controller: "SomeController",
    templateUrl: function(params) { return "Some/Template/";}
 }
```

This was working in the past, now I am getting the following error.

> Http request configuration url must be a string. Received: function(params).

**Edit 1:**

Ok the problem seems not to be with UI-router but with the ui-bootstrap $modal open function. When I pass the template from ui-router to the modal open that is where it's not being resolved to the proper state. Falling back to 1.2.26 makes it work again.

(bootstrap version 0.11.0)

Any ideas?

Thanks,
Thanos

Answer (score 1):

There is [a working example](http://plnkr.co/edit/eVlfNJNHSlRJeMEBvUV9?p=preview)

With those versions of angularJS and UI-Router

```
src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.6/angular.js"
src="//rawgit.com/angular-ui/ui-router/0.3.1/release/angular-ui-router.js"
```

This is working as expected

```
  .state('new', {
      template: '<ui-view />',
  })
  .state("new.state", {
    url: "/some/url",
    controller: "SomeController",
    templateUrl: function(params) { return "Some/Template/tpl.html";}
  })
```

Check it [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/eVlfNJNHSlRJeMEBvUV9?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks I'll try this and let you know. Just wanted to make sure it's not an appropriate behavior for the new angular version. UI router version is 0.2.18 for me.